# Error: import React, {Component} from 'react'; SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error in my debug console of VSCode although my project is successfully running on both the iOS and Android simulators

EDIT:
Environment details: 
React : 16.9.0
React Native : 0.61.1
Node: 12.13.0
NPM: 6.12.0

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Here is my code :

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
// import {FlatList, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {FlatList} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import UserSummary from '../components/UserSummary';

class AllFriendsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      friends: [],
      friendsData: [],
    };
    this.tempFriends = [];
    this.tempFriendsData = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchFriends()
      .then(() =>
        this.setState({
          friends: this.tempFriends,
        }),
      )
      .then(() => this.fetchEachFriend());
  }

  async fetchFriends() {
    const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    await firestore()
      .collection('Friendships')
      .where('uid1', '==', `${uid}`)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.empty) {
          null;
          console.log('DOC: ', doc.empty);
        } else {
          doc.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap.data().uid2);
            this.tempFriends.push(snap.data().uid2);
            console.log(this.tempFriends);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error DOC1 ', err));
    await firestore()
      .collection('Friendships')
      .where('uid2', '==', `${uid}`)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.empty) {
          null;
          console.log('DOC2: ', doc.empty);
        } else {
          doc.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap.data().uid1);
            this.tempFriends.push(snap.data().uid1);
            console.log(this.tempFriends);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error DOC2 ', err));
  }

  fetchEachFriend() {
    this.state.friends.forEach(uid => {
      console.log('UID: ', uid);
      firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(`${uid}`)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          console.log('Friend Data ', doc.data());
          this.tempFriendsData.push({
            uid: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
          });
        })
        .then(() => this.setState({friendsData: this.tempFriendsData}))
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error fetchEachFriend(): ', err);
        });
    });
  }

  _renderItem({item}) {
    return (
      <UserSummary
        email={item.data.email}
        username={item.data.username}
        uid={item.uid}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log('STATE RENDER: ', this.state.friendsData);
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.friendsData}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default AllFriendsScreen;
```

It is a react native project using google's firebase cloud firestore as a database. All the interactions with the database are running successfully 
Please guide me

Thank you

Comment: Did you put this line at the top of the file?

Comment: @nafeesahmed is it important?

Comment: @nafeesahmed yes

Comment: @yashatreya can you provide us some code, please?

Comment: sure, just a moment

Comment: yeah I can provide

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: Ok I am checking..

Comment: @yashatreya it seems that the problem is in your summary component, comment it for a short time and check if it works.

Comment: @J.Doe that didn't work, I got the exact same error

Comment: your code is working properly with no error in my vscode

Comment: @nafeesahmed can you tell me details about your environment??

Comment: I have added my environment details in the question

Comment: Node: 12.10.0 -  npm: 6.12.1 -     react-native: 0.61.1 -    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6